# Python Code Not Working Properly in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, scipy

I have this Python code that clearly works but not in Jupyter notebook for some reason.  The code should return a graph like the one pictured here: [Correct Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBID6.png)

However, when I run the code in Jupyter notebook the graph looks nothing likes this [Wrong Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXdoU.png).  Not sure what may be causing the discrepancy.  The code is written below.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Be warned in advance, the code takes about 17 mins to run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate


G = 6.6743*10**(-11) #Gravitational Constant
M = 10*(1.988*10**30) #Mass of the Black Hole (kg)
m = 1*(1.988*10**30) #Mass of the Companion Star (kg)
Mt = M + m #Total Mass(kg)
q = m/M #Mass Ratio
c = 2.99792458*10**8 #Speed of Light (m/s)
Period = 10 #Orbital Period (Days)
P = Period*86400 #Orbital Period (Seconds)
phi = 0.001*(np.pi/(180)) #Inclination from Line-of-Sight
t0 = Period/2 #Pulse Mid-Point
a = ((P**2*G*(Mt))/(4*np.pi**2))**(1/3) #Semi-Major Axis
omega = ((G*(m + M))/a**3)**0.5 #Angular Velocity
vtran = a*omega #Transverse Velocity
Rs = (2*G*M)/c**2 #Schwarzschild Radius
Rein = (2*Rs*a)**0.5 #Einstein Radius
te = (Rein/vtran)/86400 #Einstein Time
u0 = (a/Rein)*phi #Closest Angular Approach
pstar = ((1*(6.957*10**8))/Rein)
t = np.linspace(0,P,15000) #Time Vector
u = ((u0**2)+((((t/86400)-t0)/te))**2)**0.5 #Angular Separation

U=lambda r:(1-(3/2)*((pstar**2-r**2)/pstar**2)**0.5)
gamma = 0.3


#bottom part funtion
pre_bottom=lambda r:r*(1-gamma*U(r))

#integrates bottom part
bottom_res,bottom_err=integrate.quadrature(pre_bottom,0,pstar,maxiter=100)
bottom=2*np.pi*bottom_res


#array for values
A=np.empty(len(u))

#def top part of function
pre_top=lambda r,th:(1-gamma*U(r))*(r*(u[i]**2 + r**2 - 2*u[i]*r*np.cos(th)+2))/((((u[i]**2 + r**2 - 2*u[i]*r*np.cos(th)))**0.5)*(((u[i]**2 + r**2 - 2*u[i]*r*np.cos(th)+4))**0.5))

#change upper bound on number of subineverals for integration
options={'limit':100}

#take integral of top for all time values
for i in range(len(u)):
    top_res,top_err=integrate.nquad(pre_top,[[0,pstar],[0,(2*np.pi)]],opts=[options,options])
    #get value of A
    A[i]=top_res/bottom


plt.plot(t,A)
plt.xlim([426000, 438000])

plt.show()
```

Comment: How do you know the correct plot is correct? What are these plots supposed to represent? Do you have the code for the original plot? Please edit your question to contain these details.

Comment: Hello!  The "correct" plot was generated using the code mentioned in the question in Python.  I know it is correct as I generated the exact same plot in Mathematica which also happens to match a research paper.  The issue is that the code does not give the correct shaped plot in Jupyter notebook specifically.  So it gives the correct result elsewhere but not in Jupyter.  As for the detail of the plot, it is a microlensing pulse where a star appears brighter for a time due to gravitational lensing (apologies if that is very technical)